How to select many relate table record in surrealdb
I have a surrealdb schema like this

Now what i need is select all the apis and folders and collection that belong to single workspace
the query that i have is this,
SELECT 
->workspace_to_collection->collection.* AS collection,
(
    SELECT 
        ->collection_to_folder->folder.* 
        AS folders 
    FROM collection 
) AS collection.folder 
FROM workspaces:4yuie4oj7jrrhqvs3m7m;

and this give a result like this,
[
{
    collection: [
        {
            description: 'Collection 2 description',
            folder: [
                {
                    folders: [
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 3 description',
                            id: folder:abu30525i5w0cbz5v2xf,
                            name: 'folder 3',
                            path: '/old',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:28:08.053Z'
                        },
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 2 description',
                            id: folder:hj5k62gs0frezfctds6e,
                            name: 'folder 2',
                            path: '/new',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:27:58.921Z'
                        },
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 1 description',
                            id: folder:ovmriv3z8xf11p4tiqbd,
                            name: 'folder 1',
                            path: '/create',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:27:47.816Z'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    folders: []
                }
            ],
            id: collection:icloni09dj0pl8knp6qi,
            name: 'Collection 2',
            path: '/dog',
            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:24:23.091Z'
        },
        {
            description: 'Collection 1 description',
            folder: [
                {
                    folders: [
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 3 description',
                            id: folder:abu30525i5w0cbz5v2xf,
                            name: 'folder 3',
                            path: '/old',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:28:08.053Z'
                        },
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 2 description',
                            id: folder:hj5k62gs0frezfctds6e,
                            name: 'folder 2',
                            path: '/new',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:27:58.921Z'
                        },
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 1 description',
                            id: folder:ovmriv3z8xf11p4tiqbd,
                            name: 'folder 1',
                            path: '/create',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:27:47.816Z'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    folders: []
                }
            ],
            id: collection:g3f7ep3th6jbv2b9kcbd,
            name: 'Collection 1',
            path: NULL,
            timestamp: d'2024-12-08T14:25:33.920Z'
        }
    ]
}
]

the result structure that i need is
collection: [
        {
            description: 'Collection 2 description',
            folder: [
                {
                    folders: [
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 3 description',
                            id: folder:abu30525i5w0cbz5v2xf,
                            name: 'folder 3',
                            path: '/old',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:28:08.053Z'
                            api: []
                        },
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 2 description',
                            id: folder:hj5k62gs0frezfctds6e,
                            name: 'folder 2',
                            path: '/new',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:27:58.921Z'
                            api: [
                                  {method:"post",path"/"....}
                                 ]
                        },
                        {
                            description: 'Folder 1 description',
                            id: folder:ovmriv3z8xf11p4tiqbd,
                            name: 'folder 1',
                            path: '/create',
                            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:27:47.816Z'
                            api: [apis here]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            id: collection:icloni09dj0pl8knp6qi,
            name: 'Collection 2',
            path: '/dog',
            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:24:23.091Z'
        },
        {
            id: collection:icloni09dj0pl8knp6qi,
            name: 'Collection 2',
            path: '/dog',
            timestamp: d'2024-12-09T04:24:23.091Z'
            folder: []
        }
      ]

that is the structure that i need it like select every api and folder belong to this collection that is in this workspace with this id

can you please try, if SELECT *, (SELECT (SELECT *, ->has->api.* AS api FROM ->collection_to_folder->folder) AS folders FROM ->workspace_to_collection->collection) AS collections FROM workspaces:4yuie4oj7jrrhqvs3m7m; returns the desired structure?
